# How to use the CLLocationManager to update location without asking user to enable the service?

Tags: location, mkmapview, cllocationmanager, prompt

Is there any way to test the user location service is enabled or not without
asking user?

What I want to do is to use the user location information if the service is 
already on, or not to use it if the service is off. I don't want to ask user
to enable the service.

Is there any method to do this trick?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use [`locationServicesEnabled`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html)

```
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
    // do you stuff
}
```

Comment: It seems not working for me.
Here is what I did:

`if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
    CLLocationManager *clManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [clManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [clManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
`
And it still asked me if I allow to use user location or not.

Comment: @Steven - It will always ask the user whether they want to allow the app to use their location or not. Location can be enabled for device, but disabled for your device. The user needs to give explicit permission to your app to use the location.

Comment: @Steven - reading this makes me sound retarded - "Location can be enabled for device, but disabled for your device.". What I meant was, location can be enabled for device, but disabled for your app :)